# how to plot in a sequential manner

Tags: r, plot

how can I plot this data

```
 df<- structure(list(place = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("1US", "3US", "40US"), class = "factor"), 
    name = structure(1:9, .Label = c("A", "AA", "AAA", "B", "BB", 
    "BBB", "C", "CC", "CCC"), class = "factor"), value1 = structure(c(9L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("111.92392", 
    "319.85038", "320.90968", "321.86427", "485.42187", "497.95166", 
    "84.0712", "869.32259", "96.99223"), class = "factor"), value2 = structure(c(3L, 
    8L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 7L), .Label = c("140.7803", "208.4945", 
    "230.4867", "234.5396", "238.0624", "242.9943", "247.601", 
    "281.0763", "286.759"), class = "factor"), value3 = structure(c(6L, 
    4L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("158.31085", 
    "16.12737", "210.10137", "233.71739", "24.3654", "37.19961", 
    "41.34156", "83.06333", "96.98529"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("place", 
"name", "value1", "value2", "value3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I am trying to plot it in this way. I have 3 places 1US,3US and 40US

I want to have them instead of week 1, week2 and week 3 in attached figure

```
A with 3 different color for 3 values 
AA with the same 3 different color for 3 values
AAA with the same 3 different color for 3 values
```

etc etc

Then

[image]

In stead 1, 2 and 3 in x axis, it should be A, AA and AAA

or for the B , BB and BBB, it can be like below

[image]

Comment: Not clear, what is on x-axis?

Comment: @zx8754 **x axis is the name**

Comment: Your data is actually `character` representation of numbers, contributing to significant doubt of the data source. Though I understand that you want "Week 1" replaced with "1US" (for example), it is not at all clear how `name` and `value`s are supposed to map into the dot plot above. Are you looking for something like `stripchart(..., method="stack")`?

Comment: @r2evans yes that would be great. actually I just want to show that in 1US and A, how the 3 values changes , the same for AA and AAA or ....

Comment: It is still unclear how `16.12737` and `869.32259` map onto this integral x-axis. A (stacked) `stripchart` can be similar to a histogram where you have integral-assignments (e.g., bins). Perhaps you are just targeting faceted histograms?

Comment: @r2evans are you talking about the magnitude? It is actually important to show how much these guys are different for example have a look at `111.92392` and  `247.601` and `16.12737` not in the same range but whatever shows that these three bad boys belong to CCC of 40US

Comment: Yes, the magnitude. I suggest you make a drawing (in excel, samsung galaxy note, pencil/paper, bar napkin) of what you expect of your data, then snap a pic or somehow get it uploaded. The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaGCG.png) you are suggesting does not make it easy to visualize what you want. (Please include plotting code you've tried so far.)

Comment: @ r2evans I plot it in xls. please look above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert data wide-to-long then plot with facets:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# convert wide to long, make x and y numeric
dflong <- gather(df, key, value, -c(place, name)) %>% 
  arrange(place, name)
dflong$x <- nchar(as.character(dflong$name))
dflong$y <- as.numeric(dflong$value)

# plot
ggplot(dflong, aes(x, y, col = key)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(place ~ .)
```

[image]